# Using SoapFormatter to Serialize Selective Properties of a Class

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, soap

Hi I need to serialize several fields of my class

```
class Foo
{
 Guid value1;
 decimal value2;
 SomeCustomEnum value3;
}
```

Can I serialize all fields one by one:

```
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();
            sf.Serialize(ms,value1;
            sf.Serialize(ms, value2);
            sf.Serialize(ms, value3);
            string data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Close();
```

Comment: If you do it like that you will end up with several SOAP envelopes/messages after each other. What is it that you want to accompish?

Comment: I need to stick all class members into one string. I see what you mean, it is not what i want.

Comment: And why can't you serialize the whole class?

Comment: Because it contains lots of references to third party library classes
that i cannot declare [serializable]

Comment: I belive the only solution is declare internal class that would
countain only those fields that needs to be serialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark the fields you do not want to serialize with [NonSerialized]. That way you can skip the third party fields.

```
    [Serializable]
    class Foo
    {
        Guid value1;
        decimal value2;
        SomeCustomEnum value3;

        [NonSerialized]
        int Skip = 12;
    }
```

[Edit]
New example after comment about inheritance. You can control your serialization manually:

```
class Foo
{
    public Guid value1;
    public decimal value2;
    public SomeCustomEnum value3;
}

[Serializable]
class Bar : Foo, ISerializable
{
    private int a;

    public Bar()
    {
    }

    #region Implementation of ISerializable
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("a", a);
        info.AddValue("value1", value1);
        info.AddValue("value2", value2);
    }

    protected Bar(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
    {
        a = info.GetInt32("a");
        value1 = (Guid)info.GetValue("value1", typeof(Guid));
        value2 = info.GetDecimal("value2");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Good idea. But what if my class is derived from third-party class that is not market as serialized?

Comment: In my added example you could probably loop over all properties with reflection if you don't want to hand-craft it.